# ReUse Fragments across actionBar Tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs

I am pretty new to android programming and i am developing an app called MyExpense. This app has a Account Summary page. This page is a Multi Tab activity that shows the summary of all the accounts the user has created.

The layout for all the account summary page is same. As a result there is only one layout xml file and one Android fragment class. I am using ActionBar+Android Fragment + View Pager combination to implement Tabs.
I have implemented this Multi tab activity with the help of below url
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

I have been searching from past few days on how can i reuse the same fragment across multiple tabs, but to no use. I either didnt get sufficient resource or couldnt understand the code. However at the end i managed to get thru it and now its running correctly.

I wanted to ask you all, that is this the correct way of doing ? Should i always initialize the adapter object every time the user changes the tab in `onTabSelected` method of `AccountSummaryTabActivity`? I can see the direct impact by this. The app lags when the user swipes thru each tab, as the app is try to add new fragments in the adapter object.

If this is not the correct can you please suggest what should be correct way ? (Please explain with the help of code)

**AccountSummaryTabAdapter.java**

```
public class AccountSummaryTabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
     @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

            switch (arg0){
                default :{

                    AccountSummaryFragment fragment = new AccountSummaryFragment();
                    return fragment;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**AccountSummaryTabActivity.java**

```
public class AccountSummaryTabActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

@Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        System.out.println("onTabSelected "+tab.getText());

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        RuntimeExceptionDao<Account, Integer> simpleAccountDao = dbHelper.getSimpleAccountDataDao();
        List<Account> accountList = simpleAccountDao.queryForAll();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.putExtra("selectedAccNameTab", tab.getText());

        accSummaryAdapter = new AccountSummaryTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        accSummaryAdapter.setCount(accountList.size());
        viewPager.setAdapter(accSummaryAdapter);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can some one be able to answer this question. Struggling for quite a long time.. but to no avail.

Comment: you need not do all the adapter work in the onTabSelected method.do this in the oncreate. just write the last line of setting the current item of viewpager in this.what isthe purpose of getting intent in this is notclear from code.